# Fetch hosts without domain from inventory file

Tags: ansible

I have following inventory file

```
$ cat hosts
[web]
server1.example.com
server2.example.com
```

I would like to fetch the hostname, without the part of domain (.example.com).
I tried with the following playbook, however, it is still fetching with the entire hostname..

```
$ playbook.yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ groups['web'] }}"
```

Output

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "server1.example.com"
        "server2.example.com"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Expected output

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "server1"
        "server2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you want from a [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) called `inventory_hostname_short` which basically returns anything before the first `.` found in the `inventory_hostname`.

To get this in a normal play host loop, it's as easy as:

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: show target short name
      debug:
        var: inventory_hostname_short
```

If you need to get that for hosts not in the host loop, you will have to go through `hostvars`. Here is an example to get all those names in a list for a given group running from localhost:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: show list of shortnames for group 'toto'
      debug:
        msg: "{{ groups['toto'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname_short') }}"
```

An other example to get that name only for the first server in group 'toto'

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: show shortnames for first server in group 'toto'
      vars:
        server_name: "{{ groups['toto'][0] }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[server_name].inventory_hostname_short }}"
```

Comment: The same might also work with just `{{ ansible_hostame }}` (_... as it does in my RHEL7, Ansible v2.9 environment_).

Comment: That one requires to gather_facts on the contrary of the above example. Moreover it returns the actual configured target hostname rather than the name used in the inventory.

Comment: I got this error ```"msg": "<generator object sync_do_map at 0x7f5b85d55660>"```, to solve I've add " ... | list", like this ```msg: "{{ groups['toto'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname_short') | list }}"```

Comment: @reisub83 Please upgrade to a version of Ansible which is still supported. Your error and the needed fix are only happening because you use a version lower than 2.10.

Comment: @Zeitounator but I'm using 2.10

Comment: @reisub83 [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6e19ad06415f1ff286b1c8704f2a9aae). Meanwhile, you should still upgrade to at least ansible-core 2.11 and better to 2.13.